# Are endpoints in sveltekit safe from attacks?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

One thing I don't understand in sveltekits. I keep endpoints in /routes/api/. Will they not be visible for a user in build, production? In development I can access them via the browser or postman. Is it safe?

Comment: If you have remarks on how the site works, you can take it to [meta]. Though this remark has been made many times already and has always been negatively received by the community. In general they disagree with both the "_it makes no sense_" and the "_can be disrespectful_" parts. (Doing some research on their purpose might give you a better understanding.)

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at our [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a broader question than you would imagine. A caveat first, I think it is fair to state that no deployed (i.e. publicly accessible) endpoint is ever "safe from attacks" in the absolute sense. By definition, if an endpoint is publicly accessible, then would-be attackers *can* probe it. This is not particular to SvelteKit, however, this is true for any publicly accessible API.

The fact that SvelteKit endpoints are part of the route tree does not make them more or less safe than endpoints in any other framework. There is no index page that lists all your endpoints (unless you publish one (!) or unless you improperly set indexing options in your server configuration - see Apache's [IndexOptions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions) directive, for instance).

However, any dev worth his/her grain of salt will also be able to monitor network activity through the network tab of their browser's dev tools, making it fairly easy to find out about whichever endpoints you use in your app.

Ultimately, it's your role as a developer to protect your endpoints from unauthorized access or usage. You have several tools at your disposal:

- CORS configuration will limit which websites/domains can access your endpoints (though this can ultimately be sidestepped with a Proxy API)
- 'Authorization' headers or query parameters can help implement an auth scheme via API keys, JWT tokens, etc. but will obviously require your users to authenticate
- rate-limiting and depth-of-query-limiting (for GraphQL endpoints) are also relevant topics
- usual concerns such as protecting yourself from DB injection (sanitizing/normalizing user data), etc.

However, again, I must stress that none of this is particular to SvelteKit. The fact that SvelteKit's endpoints are part of the route tree does *not* make those endpoints more or less safe than in any other framework.